# com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Calls to setPersistenceEnabled() must be made before any other usage of FirebaseDatabase instance

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having a problem when I try to setPersistence in fIREBASE,can someone please explain on how to go about it,

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_meal_details);

        if (mDatabase == null) {
            mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
            // ...
        }


       // FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

Comment: In addition to Frank's answer, you should add a check, for example `savedInstanceState == null`, to ensure that the statement is not executed again on activity restart.  Otherwise, you'll get the exception when you rotate the device.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Something like this (iirc):

```
 if (mDatabase == null) {
     FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
     database.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
     mDatabase = database.getReference();
     // ...
 }
```

Comment: does the firebase team have a best practice for this issue Frank? I've seen you provide 2 or 3 different answers to this question. Can you point us to a best practice please?

Answer (score 107):

According to Firebase Documentations setPersistenceEnabled is to be called only once (before any other instances of FirebaseDatabase are made)

So the solution to this issue for me was the following

1. You need to create a **class** which **extends android.app.Application** and **setPersistenceEnabled(true)** over there.

For Example

```
class MyFirebaseApp extends android.app.Application 

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    /* Enable disk persistence  */
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
}
```

2. In the **Manifest**, link the MyFirebaseApp class to the application tag

For Example

in your application tag add the following

```
android:name="com.example.MyFirebaseApp"
```

this should work fine.

***Also don't use setPersistenceEnabled in any other Activity.***

Comment: I tried this and I get the following exception repeatedly

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                             Process: co.transportsystems.offrie:background_crash, PID: 27025
                                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist.

Any ideas of why this happens?

Comment: This worked for me... Thanx siddhesh.. +1 from my side.

Comment: In addition to this, if you're already using `android:name` for another Application class on  the application tag and you can't change it (like using MultiDexApplication for configure the app with over 64K methods like I was doing) you can make MyFirebaseApp extend that class.

Comment: This worked for me and seems to be the way to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

Create an application class that will be used across your entire application and initialize firebase Persistence in it:
The Class should extend Application.( **ClassName** extends **Application**):

**Heres An Example:**

**FirebaseHandler class**

*You can call/name the class whatever you want to name it*

```
public class FirebaseHandler extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);   
    }
}
```

Add the application class to your **Manifest**:

```
 <application
    android:name=".FirebaseHandler"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

This way data persistance will be applied to your entire project.
Inorder to apply disk persistence to specific data.

```
DatabaseReference myRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("people"); 
myRef.keepSynced(true);
```

**This will keep your offline data synced and up to date**

```
myRef.keepSynced(true);
```

**Learn more about Disk Persistence** [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities)

Answer (score 6):

This solution works for me without extends android.app.Application

```
private static FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;

    if (firebaseDatabase == null) {
        firebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        firebaseDatabase.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
    }
    /* Do your other stuff  */
```

**OR**

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
   FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just add this at the top of your activity class:

```
static {
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
}
```

Worked for me, not sure if it's the best practice though.

Comment: Just got a crash again using this for some reason, so use at your own risk.

Answer (score 3):

If you extend a  `ContentProvider` in your app you can call `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);`
in your `ContentProvider`'s `onCreate()` method because this method is called even before the `onCreate()` method of your launcher activity. This will also be useful when you use `TaskStackBuilder` in your app to create a synthetic stack of activities to skip some activities and move forward like when you use in app notifications. So when you come back to the launcher activity moving backwards you might have already used `FirebaseDatabase` instance somewhere in your application and the error you are getting might pop up in this case as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Kotlin, the following code worked for me. I declared as private member variable at the top of the class.

```
private val firebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().apply { setPersistenceEnabled(true) }
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. Add this to your ***launching*** activity!

```
try {           
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try checking if there are any initialized firebase apps before calling `setPersistenceEnabled.`

```
if (FirebaseApp.getApps(this).size() == 0)
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

Comment: If there is any other app using firebase? is it ok to use it?

Comment: it is better you do so be initializing any apps