# Firebase Database Persistence Bug in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been using and testing my Android app thoroughly for the last 2 weeks.

I am using the Firebase Realtime Database exhaustively in my app and the most important thing is that, my app needs to **work offline seamlessly**.

I have a splash screen, where I sync all the data for a particular user node just while starting and proceed.

I using `keepSynced(true);` and `setPersistenceEnabled(true);` for sure.

Have noticed a serious issue, which is causing a lot of problem.

**Scenario 1**

I run the app for the **first time with internet connection**, the app works fine.

**Scenario 2**

I run the app for the **first time without internet connection**, nothing works. No callback is fired.

**Scenario 3**

I run the app consecutively with/without internet connection, it works fine.

**Scenario 4**

But, when I run the app after 1 or 2 days **without internet connection**, nothing works. No callback is fired.

I seems that the **disk persistence is cleared automatically**, that is why the data is not available offline and no callback is fired.

So, how can I control when the disk persistence is cleared? Is there a way to make sure that the persistence is never cleared? Is there a way to configure the size of the disk persistence also?

**EDIT**

This is what I am doing in the `onCreate()` of my application class.

```
private void initializeFirebaseDatabase() {
        if (!FirebaseApp.getApps(this).isEmpty()) {
            FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            firebaseDatabase.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi Artitra, were you able to solve your issue? I'me seeing similar issues in 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.2.0'. Since it is hard to reproduce the issues, I'm unsure if updating to the latest version solves it...

Comment: I was unable to reproduce the problem thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link out [com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Calls to setPersistenceEnabled() must be made before any other usage of FirebaseDatabase instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37753991/com-google-firebase-database-databaseexception-calls-to-setpersistenceenabled/37766261#37766261) 
 I guess this question is similar to the one in the link and its solved.

Comment: I am doing this my application class before any other instance is created. So this answer doesn't help at all.

Comment: do you have a separate class which extends android.app.Application, with     FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true); in its onCreate ? and if yes have you linked that Class to your Application with android:name="com.example.MyFirebaseApp" ?

Comment: Yes for sure. And Firebase also doesn't allow setPersistence() method to be called after any database initialization. Its throws an exception.

Comment: can you add the screenshots or the code of how you implemented setPersistence() ? it might help solve the issue

Comment: Do you call initializeFirebaseDatabase Method in all the Activities where you use Firebase References?

Comment: I had mentioned, that this is the onCreate() method of my application class.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, with a Splash screen setting `setPersistenceEnabled(true)` there, but when I called `finish()` and tried to open the app again got the error.
Solved it killing the app instead of Calling `finish()`.

I use `OnBackPressed()` to finish the activity and a `Boolean isFinishing` flag, to distinguish between sending the app to background and killing it.

And finally I kill it in `OnDestroy()` with:

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```