# Offline firebase database without content after killing app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I have a Firebase Database that I use to fill a ListView with FirebaseUI. Everything works fine (offline and online) until the app is killed and restarted without internet. When this happens, the database is empty and once the internet is back everything it synchronizes perfectl.

I use:

```
    Firebase.getDefaultConfig().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

but it doesn't change anything. What should I do to in order to have the offline Db even after killing the app?

```
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(FirebaseApp.getInstance());
    ref = database.getReference(FirebaseAuth.getInstance(FirebaseApp.getInstance()).getCurrentUser().getUid())
            .child("Tasks");
    Log.d(TAG,"User ID: " +FirebaseAuth.getInstance(FirebaseApp.getInstance()).getCurrentUser().getUid());
    Log.d(TAG,"DB: " +database);
    Log.d(TAG,"Ref: " +ref);
    mAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Task>(getActivity(), Task.class, R.layout.task_view,ref) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, Task model, int position) {
            TextView task = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.task_text);
            CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkbox); 
            task.setText(model.getText());
            checkBox.setChecked(model.getDone()==1);
        }
    };
    listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: have you got the solution of this

Comment: @saurabhdixit not really It still works sometimes and sometimes not

Comment: i got the solution , i have posted it below please try in this way..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Firebase.getDefaultConfig().setPersistenceEnabled(true);`
 try setting this in your Application Class `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);`

Check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37753991/com-google-firebase-database-databaseexception-calls-to-setpersistenceenabled/37766261#37766261). if you get errors

Answer (score 0):

You Just need to create a class like this

public class MyFirebaseApp extends android.app.Application {

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
/* Enable disk persistence  */
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
    }
```

}

and define this line in manifest file.
android:name="package_name.MyFirebaseApp">